# AndroidRuntime shutting down Fatal Exception: main Android Studio 2.2

Tags: android, android-studio

working on an app and ran into a problem only when I run it on a phone.

Here is the Run info:

```
09/24 21:02:00: Launching app
Cold swapped changes.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.crow.page3/com.example.crow.page3.Page3main" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Connected to process 1154 on device oneplus-a0001-793b4d36
I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.crow.page3-2/lib/arm
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.crow.page3, real application class is null.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.crow.page3-2/lib/arm
I/LoadedApk: No resource references to update in package common
I/LoadedApk: No resource references to update in package com.blinq.theme.CleanUI.blue
I/LoadedApk: No resource references to update in package com.blinq.theme.CleanUI.blue
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.crow.page3, PID: 1154
                  Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.blinq.theme.CleanUI.blue, iconPack:com.blinq.theme.CleanUI.blue, fontPkg:com.blinq.theme.CleanUI.blue, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.blinq.theme.CleanUI.blue, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.blinq.theme.CleanUI.blue}
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.crow.page3/com.example.crow.page3.Page3main}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TabHost.setup()' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TabHost.setup()' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.crow.page3.Page3main.onCreate(Page3main.java:54)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1154 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

I have tried several things and been over the code multiple times. below is the code for com.example.crow.page3.Page3main:

```
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.app.Activity;


import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class Page3main extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    EditText nameTxt, phoneTxt, emailTxt, addressTxt;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        //add new contact:--------------------------------------------------
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_page3main);
        nameTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        phoneTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);
        emailTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        addressTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);

        //define tabs for from add contact tabs
        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);

        tabHost.setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("creator");
        tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabAddContact);
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Creator");
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("list");
        tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabContactList);
        tabSpec.setIndicator("List");
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        final Button addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

        //What happens on :
        nameTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i2, int i3) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                //check if there was input in the text
                addBtn.setEnabled(!nameTxt.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.page3main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        if (id == R.id.nav_logbook) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new FirstFragmentLogbook()).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_contacts) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new SecondFragmentContacts()).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_map) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new ThirdFragmentMap()).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_site_info) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
                .setName("Page3main Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
                .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
                .build();
        return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
                .setObject(object)
                .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Page3main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabContactList"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textAlignment="center" />

                    <ListView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabAddContact"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/lblCreatorTitle"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="New Contact"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:id="@+id/txtName"
                        android:hint="Name"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="0.10"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_contacts_black_24dp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="phone"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:id="@+id/txtPhone"
                        android:hint="Phone"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="0.10"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_call_black_24dp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
                        android:hint="Email"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="0.10"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:id="@+id/txtAddress"
                        android:hint="Address"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="0.10"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_place_black_24dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:text="Add"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your log you are getting a null pointer exception at `android.widget.TabHost.setup()`

The problem is probably in the following lines of code

```
//define tabs for from add contact tabs
    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);

    tabHost.setup();
```

In the above code the R.id.tabHost is returning a null pointer. Please check that you have this id defined in your layout. Also if you post the code where this ID is placed I could assist you further.

**EDIT**

Ok so the problem is you are calling setup method after you have loaded the tabs using findViewById. You must call setup method before loading tabs by findViewByid.

See the screenshot below of the developer documentation.
[image]

Here is the [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html) to the documentation page. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Vipul, thanks for the quick reply. Here is the layout code:

Comment: updated the answer hope it would help you solve your error.

Comment: Hi Vipul, unfortunately it did not. I ended up starting from scratch. Thanks anyway!